# Dropdown value gets null value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I take a ClientsName for my clients Table to my Payments table in a dropdownList, so when I create a payment I take dropdown like this:
[image]

So I put a breakpoint debug on my controller and Value ClientsName always come null, but in my view it always put the first value of my dropdown

[image]

Model:

```
public class Payments
{
    [Key]
    public int PaymentsId { get; set; }

    public int ClientsId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClientsId")]
    public virtual Clients Clients { get; set; }
    public String Paymentnumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public Decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public Decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public String Reference { get; set; }
    public String Bank { get; set; }
    public Decimal Total { get; set; }

}
```

GET CONTROLLER:

```
//GET CREATE CONTROLLER

 public ActionResult Create(Payments model)
    {
        var clientList = new PaymentsViewModel
        {
            Clients = new SelectList(db.ClientsList, "ClientsId", "ClientsName")
        };
        return View(clientList);

    }
```

POST CONTROLLER (EXTENSION METHOD):

```
 public static PaymentsViewModel PaymentsCreate(this PaymentsViewModel model)
    {
        var paynew = new Payments
        {
            Paymentnumber = model.Paymentnumber,
            PaymentDate = DateTime.Now.Date,
            Amount = model.Amount,
            Discount = model.Discount,
            Reference = model.Reference,
            Bank = model.Bank,
            Total = model.Amount - model.Discount
        };

        db.PaymentsList.Add(paynew);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return model;

    }
}
```

CREATE VIEW:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Clients, Model.Clients, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
```

I really don't know what happens here

Comment: Your dropdown list in HTML has no blank value, so it will always display the first option if you do not specify which option to select. What is your question and problem?

Comment: How can I specify which option I select? NOTE: I update my view

Comment: Do you want the dropdown list to select blank, or a specific item?

Comment: @TK-421 specific item of my dropdown list, so in my clientsName of my payments Index I can show who client made the payment

Comment: @TK-421 `int selectedID = "the selected clientID";` line says "Cannot convert source type string to target type int"

Answer (score 0):

Modify your controller and specify the selected clientID.

```
 public ActionResult Create(Payments model)
 {
    ViewBag.Clients = new SelectList(db.ClientsList, "ClientsId", "ClientsName", model.clientID)
    return View();
}
```

Modify your view.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Clients, ViewBag.Clients, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
```

Comment: `int selectedID = "the selected clientID";` line says "Cannot convert source type string to target type int"

Comment: You need to assigned selectedID your ID of your selected client. I'll update my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: okay it be `int SelectedID = model.ClientsId;`, but it no changes nothing, it still no work

Comment: I suspect it's your lazy loading in your model. See my edit for what to change.